# Get path of file without drive letter - Windows 10 / Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, path

Windows 10
Java 8

When I call `getCanonicalPath` on a `File` object, I get a string like this

`C:\data\processed\Test.xml`

How do I get the same string but without `C:\` and if possible also with `/` instead of `\`?

Comment: Perhaps [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) interface can help?

Comment: @Abra Do you know how?

Comment: Of-course I do, but someone beat me to it. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you want a file path and not a URL?  What is the reason for preferring forward slashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NIO.2 API and its objects `Path` and `Paths` which is a abstraction over a file system.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\data\\processed\\Test.xml");
```

You can also get `Path` from `File` using `File::toPath`. Actually, you need to get all the **names** in the path:

```
File file = new File("C:\\data\\processed\\Test.xml");
Path path = file.toPath();
int count = path.getNameCount();                        // the count of names
path = path.subpath(0, count);                          // all the names
```

Alternatively (thanks to [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845959/get-path-of-file-without-drive-letter-windows-10-java-8/63846197?noredirect=1#comment112901465_63846197)) using `Path:relativize` (you find a relative path to the root `C:/` which is all the **names**.

```
File file = new File("C:\\data\\processed\\Test.xml");
Path path = file.toPath();
path = path.getRoot().relativize(path);
```

Here are some relevant methods:

- `path.getRoot()` returns `C:\`
- `path.getNameCount()` returns the number of **name** elements in the path (`3` in this case)
- `path.getName(0)` returns `data`, `path.getName(1)` returns `processed` etc...
- `path.subpath(fromInclusive, toExclusive)` returns a relative Path that is a subsequence of the **name** elements of this path.
- `path.relativize(path)` returns a relative path to a parameter.

The object `Path` represents an *abstraction* of the actual path. If you want to replace `\` with `/` as a String, you might need to use `String::replace`.

```
String stringPath = path.toString().replace('\\', '/');

System.out.println(path);          // data\processed\Test.xml
System.out.println(stringPath);    // data/processed/Test.xml
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could call method `toPath()` of class `java.io.File` in case the OP initially has an instance of `File` as seems to be the case from his question. Also method `replace(char, char)` of class `String` can be used to replace all `\` characters with all `/` characters, rather than method `replaceAll()`

Comment: You can also use `path.getRoot().relativize(path)`.

Comment: Or produce the end result in one step: `String stringPath = StreamSupport.stream(path.spliterator(), false) .map(Path::toString) .collect(Collectors.joining("/"));`

Comment: @Holger: I have referenced your comment. You might want to post the Stream API as your answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short answer:

```
File file = new File("c:\\tmp\\abc.txt");       //file =C:\tmp\abc.txt
String filePath= file.getCanonicalPath();       //path= C:\tmp\abc.txt
String str=filePath.replace('\\', '/');         //str= C:/tmp/abc.txt
java.net.URI uri= new java.net.URI(str);        //uri= C:/tmp/abc.txt
uri.getPath();                                  //uri.getPath() = /tmp/abc.txt
```